# Pythonnet importing class: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named..."

Tags: python, c#, python-import, .net-5, python.net

I am importing a C# dll into python using pythonnet.

```
import sys
import clr
assemblydir = r"C:\Users\Nathan_Dehnel\source\repos\TFSHygiene\bin\Debug\net5.0-windows"
sys.path.append(assemblydir)
clr.AddReference("TFSHygiene")
from TFSHygiene import QueryExecutor
```

The DLL is present inside assemblydir.

Inside TFSHygiene:

```
namespace TFSHygiene
{
    public class QueryExecutor
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I followed the answer in this question: ["No module named" error when attempting to importing c# dll using Python.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67122384/no-module-named-error-when-attempting-to-importing-c-sharp-dll-using-python-ne)

However I get this error when building:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nathan_Dehnel\OneDrive - Dell Technologies\Documents\ADO TFS\ADO TFS\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    from TFSHygiene import QueryExecutor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TFSHygiene'
```

Built with .NET 5.0 target.

Answer (score 0):

I never got it to work with .NET 5.0. For me it worked with .NET Framework 4.8. [See my answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73584450/6329629).

Answer (score 0):

For .net core, you need to add `load("coreclr")` before `import clr`:

```
load("coreclr")
import clr
```